# How to enable/disable push notification from the app?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter, remote-notifications

In my app I want to enable/disable push notification from the settings page of my app itself.Can any one suggest me a solution to turn on/off the status of app in notification center from the app ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you can register and unregister the remote notification with bellow code.

Register RemoteNotification with bellow code..means Enable notification

```
//-- Set Notification
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // For iOS 8 and above
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // For iOS < 8
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

and Disable it with bellow code.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20920/discussion-between-jeff-and-paras-joshi)

Comment: @Muzammil - Here is an updated answer till iOS 11 in Swift - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672823/5638630

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4**

Enable Push Notification (Setup from app):

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

   // SETUP FOR NOTIFICATION FOR iOS >= 10.0
   let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   center.delegate = self
   center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
         if error == nil{
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
               UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }) 
         }
   }

} else {

   // SETUP FOR NOTIFICATION FOR iOS < 10.0

   let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil)
   UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

   // This is an asynchronous method to retrieve a Device Token
   // Callbacks are in AppDelegate.swift
   // Success = didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
   // Fail = didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Delegate methods to handle push notifications

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // ...register device token with our Time Entry API server via REST
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    //print("DidFaildRegistration : Device token for push notifications: FAIL -- ")
    //print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Disable Push Notifiacation:

```
UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
```

- A document by Apple on [Push Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)