# How to partially Enable/disable Remote push notifications client side?

Tags: ios, swift

I know how to enable/disable push notifications in an iOS app thanks to the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814651/how-to-enable-disable-push-notification-from-the-app).

But I need to enable/disable push notifications **app-side** for a particular thread in the app. For example in chat section I have multiple chat rooms and I want to enable/disable push notification for the particular chat room.

Any help on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: Push notification for particular chat room should be managed from your backend.

Comment: @ivarun yes i know it can be managed from backend but is there any way to do it from append?

Comment: No, you can't achieve this from app.

Comment: From what iOS you wanna to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggest, the best way to achieve this is to change your logic back-end regarding when the notifications are sent and allow the user to subscribe/unsubscribe to each set of notifications separately.

App-side, a potential, very roundabout solution might be to send *silent* push notifications, using `content-available` ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)), implementing whatever logic is necessary to determine if the user should be shown a notification, then presenting a *local* notification if necessary. I stress that this is not a solution I advocate, but using it would depend on what control you have over the back end.