# How to block some firebase push notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have some parameters. Server send push notifications every devices but if parameters are on it can see notification with devices.

I can send firebase push notification successful and I can get parameter but I cant block notification.

How I can do it?

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        if(messageType == "some parameter"){

        }

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I dont know if it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814651/how-to-enable-disable-push-notification-from-the-app

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to receive push notifications then you just need to deny 
notification permission when your app ask for that.

Or you could disable notifications by opening Settings -> Notifications, and then turning that app's notifications off.

Comment: I have two type like "car" and "house". You can it choose on app. If you choose "car" you cant see "house" notification.

Comment: That logic should be handled by your backend, your backend will check if you choose car so the notifications for house will not be sent. @dnzcskn

Comment: I can make it on Android devices. Ios so boring :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use topics to send and receive specific type of notification. You can see
[topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot block showing remote push notifications on iOS device. As it was said the backend should handle this.